# Why do we write " plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0])" with a zero at the end?

Tags: python

While storing an array representing an image with 3 channels (here `generate_image`) why do we write a 0 at the end...

```
generate_image.shape  # im is a numpy array
# output: (1, 28, 28, 3)
plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0])
```

Instead of a `:`. Something like this:

```
plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, :])
```

The generated_image array is generated by a generative model. Some line of this array look like:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 0.00453683 -0.00352695  0.00080534]
   [-0.00027692 -0.00395737  0.0022669 ]...
```

To remove the normalization I do:

```
plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0] * 127.5 + 127.5)
```

Which gives:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[126.38482  126.80347  127.29859 ]
  [128.39748  128.35097  128.0462  ]...
```

Trying
`plt.imshow(generated_image[0] * 127.5 + 127.5)` or  `plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, :] * 127.5 + 127.5)`
gives a warning:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

And outputs a white image.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment on line number two, the image has three channels.

So when you use, `im[:, :, 0]`, it would write the first channel. Therefore you will get a grayscale image.

P.S. This is not a proper color conversion method, because you are ignoring the other channels.

And if you use, `im[:,:,:]`, it is equivalent to `im`and it will write all the three channels and you will get a color image.

**UPDATE**:

The way you are reversing the normalization is wrong. Checkout this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/simple-way-to-inverse-transform-normalization/4821/2)
Though it is for `PyTorch`, it should work for `tensorflow` too.

Comment: I am trying to display arrays shaped as (1, 28, 28, 3). Using plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0]) gives me a colored image. plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, :]) give a warning:-"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)." and outputs a completely white image...

Comment: `matplotlib` will show a color image even if you pass a grayscale image, because the default color map is color. if you need to show a grayscale image in matplotlib you need to set the `cmap` value to `gray`

Comment: You need to interpret `(1, 28, 28, 3)` as an array of rgb arrays. so to when you index it as `generated_image[0]` you will get the first color image.

Comment: "You need to interpret (1, 28, 28, 3) as an array of rgb arrays." How to do this?

Comment: just use `im[0]`